# Exporting items in list box to range in Excel

Tags: vba, excel, listbox, export

So I have scoured google and forum after forum (including the Stack) trying to figure this out. All I want to do is have an ActiveX button export the contents of a list box to a range in Excel.

Below is the code I have that adds items from ListBox1 to ListBox2. After all desired items are moved to ListBox2, said ActiveX button (SomeButton_Click) would then export all the items in ListBox2 to "Sheet15" starting at range("a1").

(Please note, this is an ActiveX ListBox that is not on an actual form. It is within a worksheet)

```
Public Sub BTN_MoveSelectedRight_Click()
    Dim iCtr As Long
        Dim n As Long, lRow As Long
         Dim cStartCell As Range
    For iCtr = 0 To Me.ListBox1.ListCount - 1
        If Me.ListBox1.Selected(iCtr) = True Then
        Me.ListBox2.AddItem Me.ListBox1.List(iCtr)

        End If
    Next iCtr

    For iCtr = Me.ListBox1.ListCount - 1 To 0 Step -1
        If Me.ListBox1.Selected(iCtr) = True Then
            Me.ListBox1.RemoveItem iCtr
        End If
    Next iCtr

End Sub
```

Below would be the button that would perform the export:

```
Public Sub SomeButton_Click()
'What code can I put here to perform the export to abovementioned range?
End sub
```

Any help would be extremely appreciated as I have spent hours trying to figure this out (as much as I don't want to actually admit this, it is true)

Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go:

```
Public Sub SomeButton_Click()
    Dim v
    v = Sheet15.ListBox2.List
    Sheet15.[a1].Resize(UBound(v)) = v
End Sub
```

If the listbox is on a different worksheet, you'll need to adjust that.

**Edit #1**

This is better:

```
Public Sub SomeButton_Click()
    With Sheet15
        .[a1].Resize(.ListBox1.ListCount) = .ListBox1.List
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: That worked great! I had adjusted the sheet and was able to get the items to populate. However, for some reason only two or more values can be exported. So if I send only one item to listbox2 and try to run SomeButton_Click() I get an error "Run-Time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error. Or if two items get sent to listbox2, only one gets exported, 3 sent to listbox2; only 2 items are exported etc. Any thoughts on why this would happen? Thanks again!

Comment: Strange. Not seen that behavior before. Can you send me a small sample showing it happen? My email address is in my profile.

Comment: I updated my original post to show you an example of what is happening. Let me know if you need a better example. Thanks!

Comment: If you store only 1 value in a variant v then v will not be converted to a 2-dimensional array, so UBound(v) will throw an error. You should check if ListBox2.ListCount is 1, and in that case do Sheet15.[a1].Value = v.

Comment: The reason why one fewer value is exported is because when you store the values of a listbox in a variant v as suggested, v will be zero based, so you should have Sheet15.[a1].Resize(UBound(v) - LBound(v) + 1, 1).Value = v.

Comment: @ExcelDevelopers The zero-based array is correct. My bad. Your first comment is not true. A listbox with only one value in the list will absolutely assign a 2d array during a List read.

Comment: Your edit worked! Thank you for your help, I now see why example 1 entirely work whilst example 2 did. Very glad to have learned this for future coding. Thanks guys, and thanks Excel Hero for your time! Accepted and upvoted! :)

Comment: @Excel Hero:  I "guessed" the bit about the 2d array ;) It is true though for ranges: if you assign a single cell's value to a variant array it will be converted to a non-array.